# Changing class with external file elements

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have my navigation in a separate file that is linked to my regular pages with a `<?php require` statement. I have a class on the `<li>` in the menu that will change the word to a white rather than gray. So In short I have:

```
<li class="active">
   <a href="">Home</a>
</li> 

<li class="">
   <a href="">About</a>
</li>
```

I need to change the class to `active` when the each page is being viewed but to `""` when it is not being viewed. I'm not sure how to do it though?

I hope this makes sense.

**Update:**

As per the comments, I thought it would be a good idea to outline what I am wanting to do maybe a little better.

1. The Navigation itself is inside a separate file called `navigation.php`
2. The actual pages are at the base of the files ex: `home, about, contact`
3. When the page `Home` is being viewed the class `active` needs to be on the `<li>` of that   menu item. When the `about` page is being viewed the class needs to be on that menu item and the menu items class for `home` needs to be blank.

Comment: You can alter the `className` property of the relevant DOM elements. It's not clear what you mean by "when the each page is being viewed".

Comment: Edit your post and include your CSS as well, otherwise we can't see the full picture.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking to do stuff when window.onfocus triggers - use JQuery class manipulation here, which is the easiest way to do it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onfocus

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

EDIT: If I understand your design, you have a navbar with links over an iframe holding the sub-pages (home, about, etc). In this case, just bind click handlers to the navbar divs that set and unset class and load the proper page into the iframe.

Comment: I answered the question with the code that I used to make it actually work. But the first link on this answer  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onfocus gave me the base for it!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually really simple.

Add Unique Id's to each one of the `<li>` in the menu

and then use the jQuery window.onfocus triggers and place this script on each one of the pages (home, about, contact)

```
window.onfocus = document.getElementById('indexNav').className=" active";
```

Changing the element ID to match each page.

So on the Home page you would have something like: indexNav for the ID

and then on the About page you would have something like: aboutNav for the id.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were looking for, I've tested it out,

```
<style>
.active{
color:white !important;
}
<style>
<script>
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(links[i].href==this.location) links[i].parentNode.setAttribute('class','color');
};
</script>
```

This dosen't require the link titles to have the same names as locations.